# How to setup a code signing certificate to use it with SignTool.exe and /a option?

Tags: windows, windows-10, certificate, mmc, code-signing

I just reinstalled my development and publishing environment on a new system. On my previous system, I was able to sign code with my certificate using the  signtool.exe command and the "/a" parameter, as in the following command:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64\signtool.exe" sign /t http://timestamp.digicert.com /a "C:\Temp\Test.exe"`

The /a option help says:

> Select the best signing cert automatically. SignTool will find all valid certs that satisfy all specified conditions and select the one that is valid for the longest.

On my new system, using MMC I imported the same certificate under the "Personal" section (labeled "Personnel" on my French Canadian system). I think I imported it under this section on my previous system but I'm not sure and can't access it anymore.

Now, on this new system, when I try to run the same command, Signtools gives this error:

> SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.

What can I do, how should I import my certificate to have it recognized using the "/a" option?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, I'm able to sign executable using the "/f" options followed by the certificate ".p12" file. But I'd prefer to use the certificate from the Window certificate store.